# Typescript Angular NGRX/Effects actions$.pipe() undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Hello I have issue with ngrx/effects - pipe undefined. Below I attached sample code which is correct along compilator but browser shows undefined pipe error.

```
constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private ethereumService: EthereumService
) { }

loadUser$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loadAccountState),
        mergeMap(() => this.ethereumService.getAccountDetails()
            .pipe(
                map(setAccountStateCompleted),
                catchError(() => EMPTY)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

AppModule:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
EffectsModule.forRoot([AccountEffects]),
```

EDIT: Even this sample has same error -_-

```
logActions$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AccountActions.loadAccountState),
        tap(action => console.log(action))
    ), { dispatch: false });
```

PS2. I am using `ActionReducerMap` which is main reducer file imported to Root as `reducers`

```
import {
  createSelector,
  createFeatureSelector,
  ActionReducerMap,
} from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromAccount from './account.reducer';

export interface State {
  account: fromAccount.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  account: fromAccount.updateAccountReducer,
};

export const selectAccountState = createFeatureSelector<fromAccount.State>('account');

//Account Selectors
export const selectCurrentUser = createSelector(
  selectAccountState,
  fromAccount.selectActiveAccount
);
```

What is wrong with my code, please for help

Comment: did you inject `actions$` in your constructor ?

Comment: Edited, yes I declared actions constructor.

Comment: Extended information added.

Comment: I moved effects to constructor and it works. I have to moce all code to strict mode.

Comment: I don't understand why, (maybe any change in versions) because my code was working but moving effect inside constructor as @UlandNimblehoof suggested, it is working. :O

Answer (score 12):

Depending how the `$actions` is declared the generated code might change when you set target ES2022 or newer.

Quick fix - add this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  {
    // ...
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
    // ...
  }
}
```

For future you might want to refactor class initialization and avoid this flag.

More info:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields
- https://angular.schule/blog/2022-11-use-define-for-class-fields

This issue can also happen when switching compiler target to ES2022 and some Jest tests fail just because of that.

Comment: this did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by updating my tsconfig.json file to reference ES2020 instead of ESNEXT.
[tsconfig keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyrQN.png)

After this update, in my effects file, I have my createEffect methods outside the constructor and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In angular 15, use

```
actions$ = inject(Actions);
```

when the lib is set to ES2022 in your tsconfig